# What is happening in this short program?

Tags: function

```
import random

class Die:
    face_value=1

    def show(self):
        return "["+str(self.face_value)+"]"

    def getFaceValue(self):
        return self.face_value

    def roll(self):
        self.face_value=random.randint(1,6)
```

Comment: What would be your best guess? Clue--it is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

simply put you're declaring a class named "Die" and defining 3 functions which do the following:

- show: returns a string with the face value of the die in brackets
- getFaceValue: get the face value of the die
- roll: gets a random number between 1 and 6, essentially rolling the die

Comment: Not sure this was really worthy of an answer, as polyfun suggested, it's fairly obvious